# yarn build not working but yarn start works

Tags: reactjs, build, material-ui, node-modules, yarnpkg

I am trying to create build react app. Using `yarn build`. But it gives error but `yarn start` works perfectly. Tried same thing on another machine then in that machine it builds successfully. But gives error on live server. what can be issue. It works perfectly locally in both machine. What can be issue.

I have tried deleting `node_modules`, `yarn.lock` and after clearing yarn cache again installed node modules. But not working. So what can be issue.

Comment: The problem may be related to native modules. or node.js version may be different, you can check this.

Comment: @AhmetŞimşek This issue raised after implementing material autocomplete. If I comment that code. It builds perfectly. And also one thing, same autocomplete implemented in another module and that works